# Getting path for img tag

Tags: php

I want to embed picture on page with script, so I need either path like

```
domain.com/fms/fms_theme/images/no_hos_photo.png
```

or

```
/fms/fms_theme/images/no_hos_photo.png
```

The question is, how to get one of these from

```
/var/www/flyer/data/www/domain.com/fms/fms_theme/images/no_hos_photo.png
```

which is

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

The thing is, domain is unknown, path is unknown, the only certain thing that picture is in

```
/fms_theme/images/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$path = "/var/www/flyer/data/www/domain.com/fms/fms_theme/images/no_hos_photo.png";
$relative = substr($path,strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));
```